# JSON.NET serialize object where property name to name that starts with dot

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Is it possible to achieve the following:

I have a class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Csutomer()
    {
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then I instantiate my class:

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
cust.Name = "Jhon Smith";

string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cust);
```

and the result will contain:

```
{"Name":"Jhon Smith"}
```

What I need is to get the json like this, notice the dot `.` before Name `.Name`

```
{".Name":"Jhon Smith"}
```

And after that to parse the Json back to my object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Declare your property as:

```
[JsonProperty(".Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: so that is valid object notation?

Comment: so i guess the properties are just string names then.

Comment: Great! Didn't knew about that!

Comment: Made a little example to verify it actually worked considering the deleted answer so I figured I'd just add it to your answer.

Comment: @TMcKeown Exactly, JSON property names are just strings and can contain just about anything, although some characters need escaping.  See [Json.org](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: The class example I gave was just a demo, and I just realized that for my need I can also use a `Dictionary<string, string>` and I can add as `TKey` any name basically and Json.Net will serialize it nicely ...